# English dialect in editing messages

Tags: discussion

Similarly to [Use American English rather than Commonwealth English for tags?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/458/use-american-english-rather-than-commonwealth-english-for-tags), I would like to know what to do when editing a message written by someone else.

The question [Is「ふむふむ」still used nowadays?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/is-still-used-nowadays) was written is very clumsy English, but had the following bit:

> I learnt  from

The whole question has been rephrased by another contributor, but the conjugation has been turned into

> I learned from

I would like to know if you think this kind of modification is acceptable/debatable.
The fact that the OP is obviously not a native English speaker doesn't help choosing the right dialect…

PS: I would personally not appreciate my grammar/spelling be Americanised by someone else, as I try to use British English as much as possible (within the limits of my knowledge).

Comment: Whoops, I had no idea that was a valid spelling.  I don't touch Commonwealth English when I recognize it (~re, ~our, ~ise, etc), but since the OP's English wasn't that good, I assumed that was a phonetic spelling mistake by the author.  If I do miss something like that in the future, feel free to reject my edit.

Answer (score 8):

While the question of dialects in tags is open (and, I think, addressed in that previous question), the rule on flavours of English *inside* questions/answers/comments is extremely clear:

[**Do not, *ever*, edit somebody else's post to match your personal dialect of English**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us/23873#23873)

If it is correct (and coherent) in the author's dialect, then leave it be.

Comment: My bad, this question did not show up as a possible match during redaction.  I knew there was something like that, but the question on tags confused my memory.

Comment: No worries. It bears repeating it here for everybody's benefit.